# キーボード上部の自作ツールバーを使用して文字を挿入したい

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

Xcode13.4.1, Swift5.6.1を使用して簡単な計算アプリを開発しています。
decimalPadにはマイナスの入力がないので、キーボード上部にツールバーを追加し、入力するような動作ができればと考えています。
複数Viewでこのツールバーを追加をしたいため、Modifierを自作して各ViewにTextFieldを配置、修飾しています。

```
// キーボード上部を修飾するために置くtextFieldのModifier
struct AddKeyboardAccesaryTextFieldModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding()
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                    HStack{
                        // ツールバーの中身
                        Button("-") {
                            // ここに選択中のTextFieldへ"-"を挿入するコードを書きたい
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

上記コード内の
`// ここに選択中のTextFieldへ"-"を挿入するコードを書きたい`
の部分、選択中のテキストフィールドへ文字を挿入する方法が分からず、途方に暮れています。
どうかご助力頂けますと幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focus系を使用すればうまくいくようです。

```swift
enum Field {
  case first
  case second
}

extension FocusedValues {
  private struct SelectedFieldKey: FocusedValueKey {
    typealias Value = Field?
  }
  var field: Field? {
    get { self[SelectedFieldKey.self]?.unsafelyUnwrapped } // unsafelyUnwrappedで合っているか不明
    set { self[SelectedFieldKey.self] = newValue }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var text1 = ""
  @State var text2 = ""
  @FocusedValue(\.field) var field

  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      VStack {
        TextField("text1", text: $text1)
          .focusedValue(\.field, .first)
        TextField("text2", text: $text2)
          .focusedValue(\.field, .second)
      }
    }
    .modifier(AddKeyboardAccessaryTextFieldModifier(text1: $text1, text2: $text2))
  }
}

struct AddKeyboardAccessaryTextFieldModifier: ViewModifier {
  @FocusedValue(\.field) var field

  @Binding var text1: String
  @Binding var text2: String

  func addText(_ text: String) {
    guard let field = field else { return }

    switch field {
      case .first:
        text1 += text
      case .second:
        text2 += text
    }
  }

  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
      .toolbar {
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
          Button("-") {
            addText("-")
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: 返信が大変遅くなりました。申し訳ありません。やはりこの方法で1つ1つのViewに実装していくしかありませんかね・・・。具体的なコードと共にご回答いただきありがとうございました。大変助かりました。

Answer (score 0):

こんな感じでどうでしょうか？

```
Button (action: minus) {
    Text("-")
}

中略

func minus() {
    let value = テキストフィールドのインスタンス.stringValue
    if value.hasPrefix("-") {
        テキストフィールドのインスタンス.stringValue = value.removeFirst
    } else {
        テキストフィールドのインスタンス.stringValue = "-" + value
    }
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。返信が遅くなり申し訳ありません。
自分の質問の仕方がよくなかったのですが、ご回答の所の
`// テキストフィールドの値をマイナスにする処理`
の実装方法が分からなかったため、質問させて頂きました。

考えているものとしては
・フォーカスされているTextFieldのTextに "-" をinsertする。
もしくは
・sendKey("-")のようなメソッドを呼ぶ。
があるのですが、こちらに該当するものを見つけられず質問させて頂きました。
引き続きお知恵をお貸し頂けますと幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `minus`の中身を実装してみました

Comment: 具体的なコードと共に回答いただきありがとうございます。特定のインスタンスではなく、今フォーカスされているテキストフィールドに"-"を挿入できればと考えているのですがそちらは難しいでしょうか・・・？頂いたコードの `テキストフィールドのインスタンス` の部分を`focusedTextField().text` のようなメソッドで実装できればと考えています。重ね重ねすみません。よろしくお願いいたします。